# Error while trying to insert data for the first time - Entity Framework 6 (Model First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I took the model first approach to create the data layer using Entity Framework 6. I completed the model, created the database and wrote an insert query. The data layer with EF is set as a separate project. My start up project is a simple windows application that performs a simple insert to the DBContext like so:

```
using (var context = new Tools.DAL.DTContext())
{
    context.QueryResponses.Add(response);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the start up project i have a reference to the data layer project (Tools.DAL); in the app.comfig of the start up project i have the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="DTContext"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=192.168.x.xxx;Initial Catalog=MyCatalogueDB;
          Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxx;Password=xxxxxx" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

DTContext is defined as:

```
 public DTContext() : base("name=DTContext")  {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

I would like to stay with code first, so i don't want to delete the exception line (which appears to solve the problem)

Here is the error i am getting when i run the code:

> ### 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'
>
> Additional information: The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: >http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715

Comment: pretty sure the `DBContext(string)` constructor just expects the name of the connection string, not `"name="`, so `"DTContext"` instead of `"name=DTContext"`

Comment: I was going to suggest that too but that Microsoft link in the error message has an example with `name=`. So yeah, drop `name=`.

Comment: thank you both. I removed the name but it didn't help. I am still getting the same error. BTW, the DBContext was generated automatically by EF

Comment: Did you fix this by the way?? WIll you plz share the solution, I am having the same issue